# number of Valid hosts in IPv6?

Tags: networking

Anyone knowing about the Address divisions in IPv6?

Comment: Any specific information you need that isn't described here?http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6

Comment: i was trying to find out number of valid hosts in ipv6 as we can calculate in ipv4 using classes and all

Answer (score 2):

The most common divisions are:

- /64 - a single subnet, i.e. one LAN
- /56 - smallest per-customer assignment
- /48 - typical per-customer assignment
- /32 - typical allocation to a Local Internet Registry (LIR) from their Regional Internet Registry

Comment: so does it mean 2^64-1 hosts in first case?

Comment: kind of, yes, although of course you could never put that many in one network ;-)

Comment: so total number of valid hosts possible would be? they will obviously depend upon the subnetting that we're using and hence will be variable i guess... isnt it so?

Comment: Theoretically, the largest amount of hosts ip6 can host is 2^128, just like ip4 can host 2^32.

Answer (score 1):

Ooops!!! There is some confusion about minimum Ipv6 prefix. the /64 prefix MAY be selected for dynamic allocation under Local Unicast (fe80::) but this does not mean for all Global Unicast, according to RFC4291.
Initially, the minimum prefix that will be allocated BY IANA (not by Internet Providers) is /64. This means that anyone with equipments connected to INTERNET MUST have ANY network prefix below /64. BTW, /65..../128 are ALSO valid. There is only one restriction: The IP must be unique. The condition of host addressing using EUI-64 MAY be used at Global Unicast outside range of FE80:: but MUST be used for FE80:: host addressing.

Comment: My consumer-grade subscription uses a /48, so IANA must have given my ISP a larger block. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#IPv6_address_space) claims in "General allocation": *RIRs assign smaller blocks to ISPs, which then distribute this in /48 sized parts to their clients.* And finally, an IANA draft [IPv6 Addressing Plans](http://www.getipv6.info/index.php?title=IPv6_Addressing_Plans&oldid=2998): *All [see notes] customers get one /48 unless they can show that they need more than 65k subnets.*